# How to reverse scale on legend in plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, legend

I am using plotly on python.
I have a legend which is a colour scale 0-100%.
Currently 100 is at the top and 0 at the bottom.
I want 100 to be the bottom and 0 the top.
Is this possible?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- you can define the ticks in a color bar
- below code shows this, however the hover on the figure does not correspond to tick in color bar ...

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "x": np.linspace(0, 10, 20),
        "y": np.cos(np.linspace(0, 10, 20)),
        "color": np.linspace(0, 1, 20),
    }
)

px.scatter(df, x="x", y="y", color="color").update_layout(
    coloraxis={
        "colorbar": {
            "tickmode": "array",
            "tickvals": np.linspace(0, 1, 5),
            "ticktext": np.linspace(1, 0, 5),
        }
    }
)
```